# Can flyback transformer used for push pull converter?

Tags: flyback, push-pull

I am electrical engineering student and I am working on capstone project now. We decided to make paralleing input and series output push pull converters. (So combining two converters) However, we chose to do push-pull topology since it is best-suited for our project and we found good ic chip and then done with design. However, we are stuck now because we need to buy transformers, but all we can find is flyback transformers at coilcraft. We did found some puch-pull transformer, but we found that we have problem with either turns ratio or voltage rating or similar. I am wondering if it a good idea to use flyback transformer to make push-pull converter. If that so then is there any design consideration? If not then can you please recommend me any good websites that I can find good push-pull transformers? I tried to research about it, but still not sure. If any expert can help me then I would be very appreciate it!

Comment: please make your title describe the problem, instead of being a greeting! Thank you!

Comment: Shopping or buying recommendations are off topic as can be read [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I'd strongly consider winding my own.

Comment: I edited Marcus Thank you! Andy I am sorry that I did not know that it was off topic. I will try to be careful.

Comment: A transformer for P/P converter needs a center tap (CT). But flyback transformers don't have CT, except the ones wound with sandwich-style. Why don't you wind your own, as it's easier to find ferrite cores and coil formers than off-the-shelf transformers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a flyback transformer in forward converter mode, you'll be faced with an unusually high magnetising current, due to the transformer's low primary inductance. This is not necessarily a job-stopper, it just means that the primary drive devices will dissipate more than you would expect. With a big enough low ESR input capacitor, and low enough RDSon devices, there's no reason why you couldn't make an adequate design.

An alternative would be to resonate the primary with a capacitor, which then sources the magnetising current, and drive the primary at resonance.

The leakage inductance also tends to be higher, at least as a ratio to the other inductance.

You'll already have discovered from your research into flyback transformers that they tend not to have a centre tap, which is needed for the simplest two-device push-pull drive. A single winding will need to be driven with an H-bridge.

It would be best to source a proper forward transformer. Ungapped cores are easy enough to buy, and with few turns needed at high frequency, they much more practical to make than mains frequency ones. Design considerations are different to mains frequency ones though, so be careful where you get your equations from. Peak flux tends to be determined by heating at operating frequency, before getting limited by saturation.

Comment: Show stopper. This is a job stopper :P https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=job%20stopper